# GIven a set of strings, create a dictionary of dictionaries using them as keys to entries with default values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this:

```
set_of_strings = {'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}
```

And I want to create this:

```
dict_of_dicts = {
     'abc': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0},
     'def' : {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0},
     'xyz' : {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0} 
}
```

What's the pythonic way? (Python 2.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> set_of_strings = {'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}
>>> dict_of_dicts = {}
>>> for key in set_of_strings:
...     dict_of_dicts[key] = {'pr':0, 'wt':0}
... 
>>> print dict_of_dicts
{'xyz': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'abc': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'def': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}}
```

---

As a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {k:{'pr':0, 'wt':0} for k in {'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}}
{'xyz': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'abc': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'def': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}}
```

---

Alternatively, you can do something like:

```
>>> set_of_strings = {'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}
>>> value = {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0} 
>>> dict(zip(set_of_strings, [value]*len(set_of_strings)))
{'xyz': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'abc': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'def': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`dict.fromkeys`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys({'abc', 'def', 'xyz'}, {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0})
>>> d
{'xyz': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'abc': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}, 'def': {'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}}
```

**NOTE**:

The value specified (`{'pr': 0, 'wt': 0}`) is shared by all keys.

```
>>> d['xyz']['py'] = 1
>>> d
{'xyz': {'pr': 0, 'py': 1, 'wt': 0}, 'abc': {'pr': 0, 'py': 1, 'wt': 0}, 'def': {'pr': 0, 'py': 1, 'wt': 0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers show, there are several ways to achieve this, but IMO the most (only?) pythonic way is using a dict comprehension:

```
keys = ...
{ k: { 'pr': 0, 'wt': 0 } for k in keys }
```

If the values were immutable, `dict.fromkeys` is good, and is probably faster than dict comprehension.